# overriding the MuiTable-root class in material table

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I have been trying to override the muitable-root class when using the material table component but havent been able to get it to work. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

style:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
      '& .MuiTable-root': {
        borderCollapse: 'separate'
      }
    }
  }))
```

component call:

```
<MaterialTable
      classes = {useStyles.root}
      tableRef = {ref}
      icons = {tableIcons}
      title = {props.title}
      columns = {props.columns}
      data = {props.data}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `classes` prop you need to use predefined rule name.

You can find them in [CSS part of components API](https://material-ui.com/api/table/#css)

As You can see for `.MuiTable-root` there is `root` rule name so You have to use it as key in you `classes` object.

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  myCustomStyles: {
    border: "1px solid red"
  }
});
```

```
const myClasses = useStyles();

<MaterialTable
      classes = {{
        root: myClasses.myCustomStyles
      }}
      tableRef = {ref}
      icons = {tableIcons}
      title = {props.title}
      columns = {props.columns}
      data = {props.data}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked the source code of `material-table`, and looks like it's not accepting `classes` for styling most of the appearance, it only affects the Footer part. Check [this function](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/blob/master/src/material-table.js#L728) and [this line](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/blob/master/src/material-table.js#L753), that's the only place using `props.classes`.

If this style can be applied globally, maybe you could use material-ui's customization suggestion, [here](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#global-css-override) or [here](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#global-theme-override).